# Array index out of range. Swift. Table View

Tags: arrays, swift, image, tableview

I got a fatal error: Array index out of range. The error comes from                 `let profilePicture = tempProductPictureArray[count]` when tempProductPictureArray[count] is nil. I am wondering do I set something wrong on imageArray?

```
var imageArray = [[PFFile]]()
........
.......
.......
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell:MarketTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MarketCell") as! MarketTableViewCell
    let tempProductPictureArray = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    // tempProductPictureArray.count is something like [nil / PFFile(image), nil / PFFile(image) .....]
    if tempProductPictureArray.count != 0 {
        var hasImage = false
        var count = 0
        while hasImage == false {
            let profilePicture = tempProductPictureArray[count]
            if profilePicture != nil {
                profilePicture!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { data, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        self.appDelegate.displayMyAlertMessage((error?.localizedDescription)!, userVI: self)
                    } else {
                        cell.productImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                }
                hasImage = true
            } else if count == tempProductPictureArray.count {
                cell.productImage.image = UIImage(named: "Profile Picture")
            } else {
                count += 1
            }
        }
    } else {
        cell.productImage.image = UIImage(named: "Profile Picture")
    }
```

data source

```
func refreshResults(){
    ...
    ...
    ...
sameObjectInQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (sameObjects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    for var i = 0; i <= tempUniqueTitle.count - 1; i++ {
        tempProductImage = [PFFile]()
        for sameobject in sameObjects! {
             if sameobject.objectForKey("detailsImage") != nil {
                 tempProductImage.append(sameobject.objectForKey("detailsImage") as? PFFile)
             } else {
                 tempProductImage.append(nil)
             }
        imageArray.append(tempProductImage)
}
....
```

Comment: I only see `let profilePicture = tempProductPictureArray[count]` in the code. Where is `tempProductPictureArrayFromDemand`?

Comment: please add the other methods of your UITableViewDataSource implementation

Comment: Sorry. It should be The error comes from  let profilePicture = tempProductPictureArray[count] when tempProductPictureArray[count] is nil.

Comment: datasource is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trace through your code, assuming that `tempProductPictureArray` contains one item.   `tempProductPictureArray.count` will be 1 and that item is at offset 0.  Presumably, it's a nil optional and you want to skip over it.

Since `count` is not equal to  `tempProductPictureArray.count`, you add one to count and try to fetch something from the array at that location (offset 1).  However, we've said the only element in the array is at offset 0, so...crash.

You need to make sure that `count` is always less than  `tempProductPictureArray.count`.

Comment: Oh ya. thank you.
I put this above the tempProductPictureArray.count if count == tempProductPictureArray.count {
                cell.productImage.image = UIImage(named: "Profile Picture") } else {